# How to move certain line text, variable position, to specific column

Tags: python, search, notepad++, text-formatting

I have a text file with hundreds of lines that I want to move a particular end chunk of each line (variable beginning length, everything after the "AS") to a particular column position.

This is a task I need to do regularly.  I do this particular formatting now in Notepad++ with find-n-replace actions, but last steps are tedious manual tab line ups.

The raw pattern is like (this is after some initial formatting manipulations via find-n-replace actions):

red.id AS red_identifier  
   red.c AS red_color  
   mbr.red_mbr AS red_member  
   stat.red_stat AS red_status

I want the formatting to be like this, all "AS ..." portions starting at column x:

red.id                AS red_identifier  
red.c                  AS red_color  
mbr.red_mbr    AS red_member  
stat.red_stat     AS red_status

Any help would be so very appreciated!  Can this be handled in Notepadd++?  Python (only language I know) script advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 2 step:

1. Modify the tab width to a specific width, here, I'm using 25 [image]
2. - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
   - Find what: `\h+(?=AS\b)`
   - Replace with: `\t`
   - *check Wrap around*
   - *check Regular expression*
   - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?=         # start lookahead, zro-length assertion to make sure we have after:
  AS        # literally AS
  \b        # word boundary to make sure we don't match AS... (i.e. Asterisk)
)           # end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
red.id                   AS red_identifier
red.c                    AS red_color
mbr.red_mbr              AS red_member
stat.red_stat            AS red_status
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with 4 separate regex based find/replace:
The replacement varies based on the number of leading spaces needed to achieve the desired `column x` alignment.

Regex to the match:

[image]

After replace:

[image]

So the regex and replace for each group would be:

Find what: `(?:(AS red_[i].+))` // captures the `AS red_identifier` text
Replace with: (7 leading spaces)$1         // $1 is replaced by the text captured

Find what: `(?:(AS red_[c].+))` // captures the `AS red_color` text
Replace with: (8 leading spaces)$1

Find what: `(?:(AS red_[m].+))` // captures the `AS red_member` text
Replace with: (2 leading spaces)$1

Those 3 replacements will align to `AS` on the last line with `AS red_status`. You can of course adjust the spacing, but the regex to the last line in your example would be:

Find what: `(?:(AS red_[s].+))` // captures the `AS red_status` text
Replace with: (n leading spaces)$1   // `n` here would be whatever number of spaces you might want.

Should you add spacing to the 4th line, then the spacing amount used there would need to be added to the first 3 to maintain the desired `column x` alignment.

For example, if you want 4 extra spaces before the AS in the last line, then:

- the 1st line match would need 11 leading spaces before $1
- the 2nd line match would need 12 leading spaces before $1
- the 3rd line match would need 6 leading spaces before $1

... to keep the `column x` aligned to AS.